# How To Reach Local Insecure (HTTP) Server From A Secure (HTTPS) Page

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, https, mixed-content

I have a site running on https, which is trying to reach a windows service that is running as an http server, using an http localhost address, via AJAX.  However, this is returning an "Access is denied" error.  It works fine when calling from http, but that is not an option beyond testing.  We are also limited to using Internet Explorer (9+) only.

I have set the "Allow mixed content" security setting to "Enable" for the respective zone, but it is still getting blocked.

The AJAX call looks like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:5923/somefunction',
        data: {
            sid: sid,
            aid: aid
        },
        success: function (ret) {

            //...
        },
        error: function (error, status, errThrown) {
            alert(errThrown);
        }
   });
```

I know modifying the windows service to function over https is the best solution long term, but does anyone have any suggestions for IE settings that would allow mixed active content, or any other interim fixes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable cross-origin access so go to Tools->Internet Options->Security tab, click on “Custom Level” button for the zone of your choice. Go to Miscellaneous -> Access data sources across domains setting and select “Enable” option.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  However, I actually already had that set to enabled for the respective zone (trusted).

Answer (score 0):

Is this code blocked by SOP (Same Origin Policy)?
If so, set "crossDomain" setting to "true".
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/